# Duplicated values after select related field

Tags: python, django, full-text-search

I have a simple forum application:

```py
# models
class Topic(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Message(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name='messages')

# views
class SearchView(ListView):
    ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        search_vector = SearchVector('messages__text')
        search_query = SearchQuery(self.request.GET.get('query'))
        topics = Topic.objects.annotate(
            rank=SearchRank(search_vector, search_query)
        ).filter(rank__gte=0.0).order_by('-rank')
        return topics
```

I want have full text search in my forum.
Everything works but in topic query results I got duplicated objects.

```
<QuerySet [<Topic: 1>, <Topic 1>, <Topic 2>, <Topic 1>, ...]>
```

I think that it happens because of multiple messages in one topic that gives me different rank values.

How can I remove duplicated topics but keep rank ordering?

Answer (score 0):

All you should need to do is add `.distinct()` to the end of your queryset.

You should review [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#distinct), which has some specific notes on using `distinct()` in conjunction with `order_by()`. It shouldn't affect you here, since you're not ordering by a related model field, but something to look out for.

```
class SearchView(ListView):
    ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        search_vector = SearchVector('messages__text')
        search_query = SearchQuery(self.request.GET.get('query'))
        topics = Topic.objects.annotate(
            rank=SearchRank(search_vector, search_query)
        ).filter(rank__gte=0.0).order_by('-rank')

        return topics.distinct()
```

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue and even after adding distinct() didn't solve the issue. it's still returning the multiple same objects. Could you please help me